# Unknown column in where clause with CASE

Tags: mysql

What is the wrong here, or missing?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (f_username = '$username' AND table1.code = table2.code) THEN '1'
            ELSE '0'
             END as is_favorite
 FROM (
      SELECT *
        FROM favorites
       WHERE f_username='$username'
         AND code = table2.code
     ) table1
INNER JOIN (
       SELECT * 
         FROM groups
        WHERE gname LIKE '%$text%'
     ) table2
```

there error is

> **Unknown column 'table2.code' in 'where clause'**

EDIT

I have two tables (groups / favorites)

groups structure is:
gname / code

favorites structure is:
code / f_username

What am looking for is I want to get list of groups in specific query and I want to loop for each group check the favorites based on username if he added as favorite or not.

Comment: Are you sure you are not aliasing table2's code column to a different name? MySQL is complaining that this column does not exist so check that you did not call it something else or alias.

Comment: Am sure. groups table and favorites table has code column

Comment: SELECT        table1.code, table1.f_username
FROM            (SELECT        code, f_username
                           FROM            dbo.favorites
                           WHERE        (f_username = '$username') AND (code = table2.code)) AS table1 INNER JOIN
                             (SELECT        gname, code
                                FROM            dbo.groups
                                WHERE        (gname LIKE '%$text%')) AS table2 ON table1.code = table2.code

Comment: try above code...

Comment: In the FROM (SELECT * you are joining on table2.code which doesn't exist there

Comment: @combo_ci the same Unknown column 'table2.code' in 'where clause'

Comment: then the code column douse not belong group table

Comment: @Simon Could you explain please

Comment: @combo_ci code is a column in groups table

Comment: could you please edit your question and add 2 group column to question?

Comment: Please PLEASE read this and [edit] your question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: @combo_ci  I added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong or missing? You are referring to the table alias name `table2` in your first subquery. That alias is not in scope in that subquery, because you only define it as an alias for your second subquery. This is the offending bit of SQL: `AND code = table2.code`.  The query parser didn't get to your SELECT clause because it tries to figure out what columns it has available first.

Your query has a strange structure. You probably should consider simply joining your tables like this.

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM favorites f
  JOIN groups g ON f.code = g.code 
 WHERE f.f_username = '$username'
   AND g.gname LIKE '%$text%'
```

But you didn't show any sample data or explain the result you want, so I'm guessing.

Comment: This is working fine, but what am looking for is when I get some groups I want to check if the user is added in favorites (other table) or not for example: two groups (group1,group2) and the username is abdulaziz who add group2 in favorite

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
SELECT  gname, CASE WHEN favorites.code IS NULL THEN '0'
                ELSE '1'
                END as is_favorite
FROM    groups
WHERE   WHERE gname LIKE '%$text%'
LEFT JOIN favorites ON groups.code = favorites.code
```